# Custom Validator on Controller methods

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I followed this tutorial to create custom validators:
http://codetutr.com/2013/05/29/custom-spring-mvc-validation-annotations/

And according to this one, it's possible to validate request aguments with JSR-303 validation annotation:
https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2015/08/29/validating-spring-mvc-request-mapping-method-parameters/

My custom ConstraintValidator is never invoked. Here is my code:

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/json")
@Validated
public class JsonResource {

    @RequestMapping(method = POST, consumes=APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE"))
    public void postJson(@SafeHtml @RequestBody JsonNode jsonQuery){
        // post a foo
    }

}
```

SafeHtml annotation:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = {SafeHtmlJsonValidator.class})
@Target( {ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SafeHtml {

    String message() default "{SafeHtml}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

Custom ConstraintValidator:

```
@Component
public class SafeHtmlJsonValidator implements ConstraintValidator<SafeHtml, JsonNode> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(SafeHtml constraintAnnotation) {}

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(JsonNode value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        // validate my JSON

        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem is that `SafeHtmlJsonValidator.isValid()` is never invoked.

Tested with Spring 4.2.6.RELEASE

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant, the author in the post created a Subscriber.java in which it had the year.clss reference, but you are using the @SafeHtml right in the parameter of the Json post request method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want to convert everything to a `DTO` you can add `MethodValidationPostProcessor`

```
@Bean
public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
    return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
}
```

that will allow you to add validation annotation to method field directly

like

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/json")
@Validated
public class JsonResource {

    @RequestMapping(method = POST, consumes=APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE"))
    public void postJson(@SafeHtml @RequestBody JsonNode jsonQuery){
        // post a foo
    }

}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed !

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if annotating with custom validation (@SafeHtml) onto a @RequestBody parameter will work in a controller method. It will surely work for @RequestParam and @PathVariable in the controller method, when its a get request.

For post requests, I believe there should be a POJO bean representing the request body, and the custom validation annotations should be placed on the attributes of this request object.

In your example you should ideally have a RequestObj.class with an attribute JsonNode, and this should be annotated with @SafeHtml.

Since you have already annotated @Validated at the class level of the controller, the controller method will then be

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, consumes=APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE"))
public void postJson(@RequestBody RequestObj requestBody){
    // post a foo
}
```

and RequestObj.class will have

```
@SafeHtml
private JsonNode jsonQuery;
//getters,setters...
```

This should trigger the custom validator. Worth a try. Note that your request json structure will change accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but in this projet, many controllers have no DTO (POJO beans), that's why I tried this way.
If it's not possible, I'll have to create POJO beans for each controller method, indeed.